# Count indexes using "for" in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, count, indexing

I need to do in Python the same as:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {cout << i;}
```

but I don't know how to use FOR in Python to get the index of the elements in a list.

Comment: I didn't put the list. what I need is to simply get the index of elements in a list. Normally I'd use a FOR in C++ or Java to get this info.

In this case, supposing that the list is ["a", "b", "c"], I need the index of a, b and c (0, 1 and 2).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops

Comment: [You should really check the python documentation before posting here.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) Also, [I would recommend checking out a python for programmers book,](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) since you don't seem to know a lot about python but understand the basics of other languages. You can also simply read through that tutorial, it will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: The short answer to your question is use `for i in range(5)`.

Answer (score 81):

If you have some given list, and want to iterate over its items *and* indices, you can use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
    print index, item
```

If you only need the indices, you can use [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range):

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    print i
```

Comment: better to use xrange() instead of range() in this case ;)

Comment: i though `range(len(my_list))` should be avoid? (for me, i would do `enumerate` but use only `index`).

Comment: @neizod: The case that you only need the indices is actually rather rare, but if this is all you need, there is no reason to avoid `range(len(my_list))` (or `xrange(len(my_list))` in Python 2.x).

Comment: By the way, you also can get the item when you're using the `range()` way: Just use `print my_list[i]`.

Answer (score 22):

Just use

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    print i
```

to iterate through your data set and print each value.

For large data sets, you want to use xrange, which has a very similar signature, but works more effectively for larger data sets. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange

Answer (score 18):

If you have an existing list and you want to loop over it and keep track of the indices you can use the `enumerate` function. For example

```
l = ["apple", "pear", "banana"]
for i, fruit in enumerate(l):
   print "index", i, "is", fruit
```

Answer (score 10):

use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> for index, val in enumerate(l):
...    print "%d: %s" % (index, val)
... 
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
for i in range(0,5): 
 print(i)
```

Comment: This would work for me because I already know that I will have always 5 items. :) But in other cases I'd need to get the indexes of unknown number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

In additon to other answers - very often, you do not have to iterate using the index but you can simply use a for-each expression:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for item in my_list:
    print item
```

Comment: In this case it will return me the items, not its indexes. =/

Comment: right - use enumerate() or for index in range(len(my_list)) then