# Python for loops has index for counter

Tags: python, for-loop

Hello I'm beginner in Python and trying to read a part of a code with for loop but can't understand it, does any body knows how there is index over loop counter? Thanks

```
updateNodeNbrs = []
for a in nodeData:
    updateNodeNbrs.append(a[0])
```

Comment: What is `nodeData`?

Comment: `a` is not a loop counter in the classical sense like `(0,1,2,...)`. It iterates through the values of `nodeData` instead and if those are in turn containers, you can index them. Try printing `a` in the loop to see the values it takes in each iteration.

Comment: If you're use to Javascript for instance - you can think of Python's for-loop as a `for var of...` instead of a `for var in`...

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating [directly over the elements](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/for_loops.html) of `nodeData`, so there is no need for an index. The current element is designated by `a`.

This is equivalent to:

```
updateNodeNbrs = []
for i in range(len(nodeData)):
    updateNodeNbrs.append(nodeData[i][0])
```

Although the original code is more [pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html).

---

If you wanted to make the index appear, you could transform the code with [`enumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22171593/5018771) to:

```
updateNodeNbrs = []
for i, a in enumerate(nodeData):
    updateNodeNbrs.append(a[0])
```

And here, `i` would be the index of element `a`, and you could use it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

See same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524209/count-indexes-using-for-in-python)

If you have an existing list and you want to loop over it and keep track of the indices you can use the `enumerate` function. For example

```
l = ["apple", "pear", "banana"]
for i, fruit in enumerate(l):
   print "index", i, "is", fruit
```